# where clause based on a select statement from another table

Tags: sql-server

I need help with a query I am writing. I basically want to select all GRNID's from one table but they have to be between dates in another table.

So I want all GRN's between two dates found in the ABSPeriodEndDate table. To find out the start date for the between clause I need to find the MAX Period then minus 1 and the max year.

To find the end date of the between clause I want I need to find both the max period and year. But I want the DateStamp column to return the results for the between clause.

Any ideas on how to resolve this I can't seem to get it working as I want to.

My query is below:

```
SELECT tblGRNItem.GRNID 
FROM tblGRNItem
INNER JOIN ABSPeriodEndDates ON tblGRNItem.DateCreated = ABSPeriodEndDates.DateStamp
WHERE tblGRNItem.DateCreated BETWEEN
SELECT ABSPeriodEndDates.DateStamp FROM ABSPeriodEndDates WHERE ABSPeriodEndDates.DateStamp = (SELECT MAX(ABSPeriodEndDates.Period)-1 FROM ABSPeriodEndDates) 
AND ABSPeriodEndDates.Year = (SELECT MAX(ABSPeriodEndDates.Year))) 
AND 
SELECT ABSPeriodEndDates.DateStamp FROM ABSPeriodEndDates WHERE ABSPeriodEndDates.DateStamp = (SELECT MAX(ABSPeriodEndDates.Period) FROM ABSPeriodEndDates) 
AND ABSPeriodEndDates.Year = (SELECT MAX(ABSPeriodEndDates.Year)))
```

NOTE: DataStamp in ABSPeriodEndDates is a datetime2 data type and the DateCreated in tblGRNItem is a datetime data type.

Example data:

```
tblGRNItem                          ABSPeriodEndDates

GRNID || DateCreated                Year  || Period  || DateStamp
1     || 01/01/2015                 2015  ||   1     || 01/01/2015 00:00:01
2     || 05/01/2015                 2015  ||   1     || 01/01/2015 00:00:01
3     || 06/02/2015                 2015  ||   2     || 01/02/2015 00:00:01
4     || 09/02/2015                 2015  ||   2     || 01/02/2015 00:00:01
5     || 19/02/2015                 2015  ||   2     || 01/02/2015 00:00:01
6     || 16/03/2015                 2015  ||   3     || 01/03/2015 00:00:01
```

So because the greatest period minus one is 2 and the greatest period is 3 I want to get all GRNID's from tblGRNItem between the datestamp 01/02/2015 00:00:01 and 01/03/2015 00:00:01 bearing in mind the datatype's are datetime in tblGRNitem and datetime2 in ABSPeriodEndDates, so the results should be:

```
3     || 06/02/2015      
4     || 09/02/2015               
5     || 19/02/2015
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your data it is impossible to give you the answer.
As it seems there is no connection between ABSPeriodEndDates and tblGrnItem. You just want to find the range of the latest periode, true?

You could do something like this

```
 WITH MaxDat AS
(
    SELECT MAX(DateStamp) AS MaxDatFound
    FROM ABSPeriodEndDates
)
,MinDat AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 DateStamp AS MinDatFound
    FROM ABSPeriodEndDates
    WHERE DateStamp<(SELECT MaxDatFound FROM MaxDat)
    ORDER BY DateStamp DESC 
)
SELECT * 
FROM  tblGRNItem
WHERE DateCreated BETWEEN (SELECT MinDatFound FROM MinDat) AND (SELECT MaxDatFound FROM MaxDat)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Shnugo that worked but I also resolved it by:

```
declare @StartDate datetime;
set @StartDate= (SELECT Max(DateStamp)
from ABSPeriodEndDates as P
where P.Period = (SELECT Max(Period) -1 from ABSPeriodEndDates)
and P.Year = (SELECT Max(Year) from ABSPeriodEndDates));

declare @EndDate datetime;
set @EndDate= (SELECT top (1) DateStamp
from ABSPeriodEndDates 
order by Period desc, DateStamp desc);

SELECT GRNID 
from tblGRNItem
where DateCreated between @StartDate and @EndDate;
```

Comment: This is quite the same... I prefer CTEs because "single-statement" calls are better to optimize. But in this case it should be rather equal.. Please vote up / mark my answer if it was helpfull, thx